# Are DTO classes generated from JDL meant to be serializable?

Tags: jhipster, jdl

Inconsistent use of Serialiable interface.

When I generate a project from this JDL, the DTO class (ThingDTO.java) implements Serializable but does not contain a serialVersionUID. The UserDTO and PasswordChangeDTO classes do not implement Serializable.

```
application {
  config {
    applicationType monolith,
    baseName test,
    packageName com.example.test,
    authenticationType jwt,
    devDatabaseType postgresql,
    prodDatabaseType postgresql,
    buildTool maven,
    clientFramework angular
  }
  entities Thing
}
entity Thing {
  name String
}
dto * with mapstruct
service * with serviceImpl
```

I expect either the DTO classes not to implement Serializable (like UserDTO), or to include a serialVersionUID (like the domain classes).

Is JHipster intending these classes to be serializable or not?

Comment: It could be useful for caching.